# Contributing sound to a SoundCloud group

Tags: python, soundcloud

[Here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#uploading) it is said how to "Contributing a Sound to a Group".
But when I do this:

```
import soundcloud

client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='...',
                    client_secret='...',
                    username='...',
                    password='...')

track = client.get('/resolve', url='...')

group = client.put('/groups/%d/contributions/%d' % (2156, track.id))
```

I have this error:

> unhandled HTTPError "404 Client Error" Fichier:
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/requests/models.py,
>   Ligne: 799

I'm sure the track is on the group.